# Place cursor at the end of text on keyup

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm making the same functionality which a command line has. When you enter some commands and then press the key up button, you will be presented with your previous command.

Now I have all that working and it works fine but I've encountered one small problem.

The problem I encounter now is that when pressing the `up` key, the cursor is placed at the **beginning** of the command, while when using the `down` button, the cursor is placed at the **end** of the comand.

Expected behaviour is that the cursor will be placed at the **end** for both.

---

What makes this different from other questions?

- The focus is already on the input field.
- It does work with the down button

---

```js
setTimeout(function() {
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs[0].onkeydown = function(e){
  //keyup
  if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    inputs[inputs.length-1].value = 'up pressed';
  }
  
  if(e.keyCode == 40 ) {
      inputs[0].value = 'down pressed';
  }
}
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="press the up or down key"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete working example and not just part of the javascript? It will be easier to help this way

Comment: @Dekel added in a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs[0].onkeydown = function(e){
  //keyup
  if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    // placed here, it prevents the key's default behaviour to go at the end of the input text
    e.preventDefault();
    inputs[inputs.length-1].value = 'up pressed';
  }
  
  if(e.keyCode == 40 ) {
      inputs[0].value = 'down pressed';
  }

}
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="press the up or down key"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh wow... okay... do you by any chance know why this is the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Use **setSelectionRange(start, end, direction)** to put the cursor where you need it.

In my case, I've used something like...

```
time[i].addEventListener('input', function (this: any) {
      var reg = /^\d+$/;
      if ((this.value.length == 2) && reg.test(this.value)) {
        //Add colon if string length > 2 and string is a number
        this.value = this.value + ":"; 
        this.setSelectionRange(2, 2, 'none');
      }
    });
```